# Heatmap of Gene intensity values in R

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, pheatmap

I have data that look like this:

| Gene | HBEC-KT-01 | HBEC-KT-02 | HBEC-KT-03 | HBEC-KT-04 | HBEC-KT-05 | Primarycells-02 | Primarycells-03 | Primarycells-04 | Primarycells-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BPIFB1 | 15726000000 | 15294000000 | 15294000000 | 14741000000 | 22427000000 | 87308000000 | 2.00E+11 | 1.04E+11 | 1.51E+11 |
| LCN2 | 18040000000 | 26444000000 | 28869000000 | 30337000000 | 10966000000 | 62388000000 | 54007000000 | 56797000000 | 38414000000 |
| C3 | 2.52E+11 | 2.26E+11 | 1.80E+11 | 1.80E+11 | 1.78E+11 | 46480000000 | 1.16E+11 | 69398000000 | 78766000000 |
| MUC5AC | 15647000 | 8353200 | 12617000 | 12221000 | 29908000 | 40893000000 | 79830000000 | 28130000000 | 69147000000 |
| MUC5B | 965190000 | 693910000 | 779970000 | 716110000 | 1479700000 | 38979000000 | 90175000000 | 41764000000 | 50535000000 |
| ANXA2 | 14705000000 | 18721000000 | 21592000000 | 18904000000 | 22657000000 | 28163000000 | 24282000000 | 21708000000 | 16528000000 |

I want to make a heatmap like the following using R. I am following a paper and they quoted "Heat maps were generated with the ‘pheatmap’ package76, where correlation clustering distance row was applied". Here is their heatmap.

[image: Heatmap using pheatmap in R]

I want the same like this and I am trying to make one using R by following tutorials but I am new to R language and know nothing about R.

Here is my code.

```
df <- read.delim("R.txt", header=T, row.names="Gene")
df_matrix <- data.matrix(df)
pheatmap(df_matrix, 
     main = "Heatmap of Extracellular Genes",
     color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 10, name = "RdYlBu")))(10),
     cluster_cols = FALSE,
     show_rownames = F,
     fontsize_col = 10,
     cellwidth = 40,
     )
```

This is what I get.

[image: Heatmap]

When I try using clustering, I got the error.

```
pheatmap(
mat = df_matrix,
  scale = "row",
  cluster_column = F,
  show_rownames = TRUE,
  drop_levels = TRUE,
  fontsize = 5,
  clustering_method = "complete",
  main = "Hierachical Cluster Analysis"
)

Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
```

Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: Why not just `heatmap(df_matrix[, -1])`?

Comment: Yes but the graph is too small, there are gene names on right that I don't want, also there is clustering on top that I also don't want. Also, I am not sure if the graph is with correlation clustering distance row like the paper

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Data should be in the question itself rather than stored on a potentially unsafe external server. What help do you need with the code exactly? It seems you have a data program rather than a coding problem. Your values are likely very skewed and you probably have missing values.

Comment: I am sure that the authors of the paper will help you if you ask them nicely for the code.

Comment: I don't know how to use this website that's why I put a link to data. My data dont have missing values but the intensity values are much larger. I need help

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my question. Please have a look at it.  I just want the heatmap like the 1st heatmap but I am unable to made one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalize the data using `scale` to archive a more uniform coloring. Here, the mean expression is set to 0 for each sample. Genes lower expressed than average have a negative z score:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pheatmap)

data <- tribble(
  ~Gene, ~`HBEC-KT-01`, ~`HBEC-KT-02`, ~`HBEC-KT-03`, ~`HBEC-KT-04`, ~`HBEC-KT-05`, ~`Primarycells-03`, ~`Primarycells-04`, ~`Primarycells-05`,
  "BPIFB1", 1.5726e+10, 1.5294e+10, 1.5294e+10, 1.4741e+10, 2.2427e+10, 2e+11, 1.04e+11, 1.51e+11,
  "LCN2", 1.804e+10, 2.6444e+10, 2.8869e+10, 3.0337e+10, 1.0966e+10, 5.4007e+10, 5.6797e+10, 3.8414e+10,
  "C3", 2.52e+11, 2.26e+11, 1.8e+11, 1.8e+11, 1.78e+11, 1.16e+11, 6.9398e+10, 7.8766e+10,
  "MUC5AC", 15647000, 8353200, 12617000, 12221000, 29908000, 7.983e+10, 2.813e+10, 6.9147e+10,
  "MUC5B", 965190000, 693910000, 779970000, 716110000, 1479700000, 9.0175e+10, 4.1764e+10, 5.0535e+10,
  "ANXA2", 1.4705e+10, 1.8721e+10, 2.1592e+10, 1.8904e+10, 2.2657e+10, 2.4282e+10, 2.1708e+10, 1.6528e+10
)
data %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale)) %>%
  column_to_rownames("Gene") %>%
  pheatmap(
    scale = "row",
    cluster_column = F,
    show_rownames = FALSE,
    show_colnames = TRUE,
    treeheight_col = 0,
    drop_levels = TRUE,
    fontsize = 5,
    clustering_method = "complete",
    main = "Hierachical Cluster Analysis (z-score)",
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How to remove column cluster? and how to increase the size of heatmap?

Comment: Do you want to exclude genes from the heatmap?

Comment: Just hide the gene names, and the dendrogram on column and increase the size of heatmap

Comment: @Huzaifa I revised my answer